# Excel VBA - Shifting values of an array of numbers by a constant without looping

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Is there a way to add a constant to an array of numbers in Excel VBA (Excel 2007) without looping?

For instance, I have the following array:

```
MyArray = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

And I want to obtain:

```
MyArray = (2,3,4,5,6)
```

Without looping.

On the Spreadsheet, if the values are in cells `A1:A5`, I can select `B1:B5` and enter the array formula `{=A1:A5+1}`

```
MyArray = MyArray + 1
```

does not seem to work (Type mismatch error).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this to increment the array by one:

```
v = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
With Application
    v = .MMult([{1,1}], .Choose([{1;2}], v, 1))
End With
```

**Update**

Here's a more direct approach that also allows for incrementing 2D arrays

```
v = Application.Standardize(v,-1,1)
```

Worksheet function methods provide a large variety of math functions but the following were the only viable options i could find for basic arithmetic that support VBA arrays in arguments and return values:

```
(u-v)/w  = .Standardize(u,v,w) 
-u*v -w  = .Fv(0,u,v,w) 
int(u/v) = .Quotient(u,v)
```

Comment: This looks very elegant, and works well. I am just having a hard time understanding how it works exactly.
`.MMult` multiplies `[{1,1}]` by the result of `Choose`. But I can't figure out what this result is.

Comment: `Choose` appends a row of ones [{1,2,3,4,5;1,1,1,1,1}], MMult then sums these the array vertically. (You can add a watch for `Application.Choose([{1;2}], v, 1)` to break the formula down.)

Comment: i've also added an improved approach i recently stumbled upon

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is kind of cheating:

```
a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Range("a1:e1") = a
b = Evaluate("=a1:e1+1")
```

Comment: simpler than mine... another possibility would be to use a workbook name instead of a range if allowed: `Names.Add "_a",a : b=[_a+1]: Names("_a").delete`

Comment: When using a name, you don't actually write anything in the Worksheet, do you?

Comment: The name is stored with the workbook and is visible in the name manager box, it is not written to the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a user defined function which would do the trick for you.  Just pass the reference cell and the increment value as arguments.

It doesn't handle cases where you have letters in the input cells so you'd need to create your own handling for that or ensure good data.

```
Function udf_IncrementArrayByVal(cellRef As Range, increment As Double)
    Dim tempStr As String
    Dim splitArray() As String
    Dim cntr As Long
    Dim arrayLength As Long

    tempStr = Replace(Replace(cellRef(1, 1).Value, ")", ""), "(", "")

    splitArray = Split(tempStr, ",")

    For cntr = 0 To UBound(splitArray)
        splitArray(cntr) = splitArray(cntr) + increment
    Next cntr

    tempStr = "(" + Join(splitArray, ",") + ")"

    udf_IncrementArrayByVal = tempStr
End Function
```